# Magento 2: is it possible to migrate only customer using migration tool

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

I want to migrate all customers from magento 1.9.0.1 to 2.1.5 Magento. I dont want to migrate product and other things. Is it possible?

When i run `bin/magento migrate:data` this command it will migrate all things product, order and customer but I dont want migrate products and orders.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes,

It is possible to migrate only customers using migration tool.

But to achieve the same you need to know which tables are required to be migrated.

so, to break the solution into major steps :

> step 1 : Comment all the non required steps
>
> step 2 : Now Solve the errors for un-mapped fields if any.
>
> step 3 : start migration by using cli command

```
bin/magento migrate:data <config.xml_path>
```

this should do the trick.

Get the idea about how tool is working and you will be able to perform above mentioned steps.

Now you asked about the steps in your comment, So, trying to answer that :

```
<step title="Customer Attributes Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Customer\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Customer\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
</step>
```

keep this step and comment others. Solve the errors if any and run the data migration tool.

Comment: can you please explain me which steps i need to comment for that? because i am working first time on that

Comment: Welcome. Happy to help :)

Comment: Customers are migrated in database but not displaying in ADMIN. can you help me? All other content is migrated except customer.

Comment: my mistake was here. Customer and all data is migrated.

Comment: if i want to migrate only ORDERS? All data is migrating even customers individually is also migrating. Want only Orders. Which is right steps for it?

Comment: @Jai Did you migrate only ORDERS in the end?

Comment: Yes, Its possible to migrate only order. I had done that

Comment: I did same but unable to login in magento 2 and unable to create new customers

Comment: @PankajBhope, Need to comment everything except above? what about "Data Integrity Step" and  "EAV Step"?

Comment: can u help me on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/284577/magento-2-customers-data-migration-volume-check-failed

Comment: Just want to add that you need to run bin/magento cache:flush && bin/magento indexer:reindex after migrating.

Comment: @PankajBhope, I am doing migration for custom modules from M 1.9.2.4 to M 2.4.1, Can you help me on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/335244/migrate-custom-module-magento-1-9-x-to-magento-2-4-1

Answer (score -1):

mode and steps in that mode you need in config.xml is

```
<steps mode="data">
<step title="Customer Attributes Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Customer\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Customer\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="Map Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Map\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Map\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
    </step></steps>
```

Files to specify in option tags in config.xml are

```
 <map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.8.0.0/map.xml</map_file>
 <customer_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-customer.xml</customer_map_file>
 <customer_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/customer-document-groups.xml</customer_document_groups_file>
 <customer_attribute_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/customer-attribute-groups.xml</customer_attribute_groups_file>
 <class_map>etc/opensource-to-opensource/class-map.xml</class_map>
```

i have perfect answer for this

rename config.xml.dist, map.xml.dist and map-customers.xml.dist as config.xml, map.xml and map-customer.xml

Comment: Is this worked for you? @Uppal

Comment: Hi @Ds Uppal are these files are enough to migrate customer data?