# How to migrate only products, categories and attributes from Magento1 to Magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, migration, magento2-migration-tool

I have clear Magento 2 installation and working Magento 1.9 show. I want to migrate just products, categories and product attributes to the Magento 2 (without orders, settings and anything else). How can I do this?

Comment: This would help you I guess
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/164989/magento-2-is-it-possible-to-migrate-only-customer-using-migration-tool

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran, the link is for how to migrate only customers? Can you explain how to migrate only products and categories? which step we need to comment?

Comment: @jafarpinjar did you solve how to migrate only categories,products and attributes only ?

Comment: any updates here?