# Migrate only products from Magento 1 to Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration

I am using Magento **data-migration tool** and can do migrate all data successfully.

I required to:

migrate only customers

migrate only Orders

migrate only Products

Followed below link and achieved migrate only **customers**.

[Magento 2: is it possible to migrate only customer using migration tool](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/164989/magento-2-is-it-possible-to-migrate-only-customer-using-migration-tool)

Followed below link and achieved migrate only **Orders**.

[Magento 2: Migrate only Customer and orders](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/268804/magento-2-migrate-only-customer-and-orders)

Can anyone help me with how to migrate only **products**?

Referred to some links but they are not useful.

If anyone worked on migration please help me to achieve the above requirement.

**Note:** If there are any free migration script or migration can be done programmatically please share the links or ideas.

Migration can be done programmatically apart from the cli? If anyone tried this share the knowledge, please

Thanks

Comment: See if this link is useful https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/406

Comment: @RajMohanR, yes checked this link not worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Please you can try migrate only products in this way:

1 backup your Magento2 database
2 in your tool > config.xml leave only `"Map Step" and "ConfigurablePrices step" for mode="data"`. Like this

```
<steps mode="data">
        <step title="Map Step">
            <data>Migration\Step\Map\Data</data>
        </step>
        <step title="ConfigurablePrices step">
            <data>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Data</data>
        </step>
    </steps>
```

3 instead of $sourceDocuments = $this->source->getDocumentList(); paste the next code

```
$sourceDocuments =
    [
        'catalog_product_bundle_option',
        'catalog_product_bundle_option_value',
        'catalog_product_bundle_price_index',
        'catalog_product_bundle_selection',
        'catalog_product_bundle_selection_price',
        'catalog_product_bundle_stock_index',
        'catalog_product_enabled_index',
        'catalog_product_entity',
        'catalog_product_entity_datetime',
        'catalog_product_entity_decimal',
        'catalog_product_entity_gallery',
        'catalog_product_entity_group_price',
        'catalog_product_entity_int',
        'catalog_product_entity_media_gallery',
        'catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value',
        'catalog_product_entity_text',
        'catalog_product_entity_tier_price',
        'catalog_product_entity_varchar',
        'catalog_product_link',
        'catalog_product_link_attribute',
        'catalog_product_link_attribute_decimal',
        'catalog_product_link_attribute_int',
        'catalog_product_link_attribute_varchar',
        'catalog_product_link_type',
        'catalog_product_option',
        'catalog_product_option_price',
        'catalog_product_option_title',
        'catalog_product_option_type_price',
        'catalog_product_option_type_title',
        'catalog_product_option_type_value',
        'catalog_product_relation',
        'catalog_product_website',        
    ]
```

4 migrate data with `--reset`